# Negative terminal of a sine generator

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, sine, signal-generator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWzUh8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I had this problem where the anode of a diode was connected to the negative terminal of a sine generator.

I wondered how it functions so that I can get the current that goes through the diode.

If lets say Vi(V1) is the positive terminal of the generator, would the negative one have the opposite wave, as Vo = -Vi?

I know it's a very basic question but I was surprised to find out that most of my university's students didn't knew the answer to it.

Comment: What sine wave generator? What does its manual say?

Comment: If you hit the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar you can draw the complete circuit and simulate it. **Important**: You need to add a ground symbol and connect it somewhere in your circuit. Hit "Save and Insert" when done to add in the schematic so we're clear what we are discussing.

Comment: funny thing about a sinewave is that the negative terminal keeps changing...

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  If it is about current through the diode, then you first have to know the peak-to-peak amplitude of the sine wave.

Comment: You didn't add the GND symbol so, I guess, you didn't simulate either? What is V2 for?

Comment: "*... if lets say Vi(V1) is the positive terminal of the generator, would the negative one have the opposite wave, as Vo = -Vi?*" You need to pick a reference point - usually GND and your measurements are taken with reference to that point. Your signal source is AC so it doesn't have a positive terminal. The output oscillates each side of zero.

Comment: Do you want to add a DC offset with V2 or what to do?

Comment: Yes, i believe V2 was added for the offset, as for the GND @Transistor , the teacher did not add it in the circuit, he straight up asked us to get the current that goes through the diode's wave

Comment: You don't need a GND symbol for a circuit diagram but you do need it for the simulator if you want to simulate it (and you should simulate it). Also, what is the amplitude of the sine generator -- 5 V as in the schematic?

Comment: I think it would be useful if you posted the exact wording of the question asked in your question. There is no mention of 2 V in it. The way you have inserted it is adding -2 V to the output of the generator.

Comment: yes that is indeed how i added 2V

Comment: @Null yes it's 5V

Comment: You need to [edit] that information into your post. It's not apparent that the sine generator has an amplitude of 5 V since it isn't shown in the schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (in the two voltage sources) an output that is Vout = \$5\sin(\omega t)-2\$ relative to ground.

The negative terminal of V1 is 0V by definition since you connected it to ground.

The positive terminal of V1 is \$5\sin(\omega t)\$, which is the same as the positive terminal of V2 since you connected them together. \$\omega\$=2\$\pi \cdot1000\$, of course.

And the negative terminal of V2 is the output so as in the first sentence. It's 2V less than the positive terminals of V1 and V2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so if we connect the ground to the negative terminal of V2, the output of the negative terminal of V1 would be Vout = -5sin(ωt)+2, thus it graph would look like shown in the linked picture right ? 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14g2HP1MGMKQ3BOqATbX5BHJbFpsLm6K9/view

Comment: That looks correct.